# Where are the Trainers for all magic schools located in MMX?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

The trainers are spread over the whole country and I have yet to find some of them. 
Does anyone know where all the Trainers are located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a html table of trainers, based on google doc found deep in upay forum..

http://mmx-trainers.reloecc.eu/

Comment: Please provide the necessary information here while also linking to your source. If that link ever goes down, we still want the core of the answer here.

Comment: @MBraedley ic, I will not answer in future at all, as it's not possible to answer "where all of them are?" in readable and clear form..

Answer (score 1):

@Reloecc I made an image from the link in your answer.

[image: An image from Reloecc's answer]